# How do I convert this class component into function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to convert the following class component into a function component.

I have made good progress (I believe) but I am running into issues converting the various references of `setState` used in the class component into `useState` for use in the function component.

**Class Component that Needs Converting:**

```
import React from "react";
import { EmptyState, Layout, Page } from "@shopify/polaris";
import { ResourcePicker } from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { open: false };
  render() {
    return (
      <Page>
        <ResourcePicker
          resourceType="Product"
          showVariants={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onSelection={(resources) => this.handleSelection(resources)}
          onCancel={() => this.setState({ open: false })}
        />
        <Layout>
          <EmptyState
            heading="Discount your products temporarily"
            action={{
              content: "Select products",
              onAction: () => this.setState({ open: true }),
            }}
          >
          </EmptyState>
        </Layout>
      </Page>
    );
  }
  handleSelection = (resources) => {
    console.log(resources);
  };
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**Function Component Code (Thus Far):**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { EmptyState, Layout, Page } from "@shopify/polaris";
import { ResourcePicker } from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";

function MyComponent(props) {
  const [resourcePicker, setResourcePicker] = useState({ open: false });
  const handleToggleResourcePicker = useCallback(
    () => setResourcePicker((active) => !active),
    []
  );

  return (
    <Page>
      <ResourcePicker
        resourceType="Product"
        showVariants={false}
        open={setResourcePicker}
        onSelection={(resources) => handleSelection(resources)}
        onCancel={() => setResourcePicker}
      />
      <Layout>
        <EmptyState
          heading="Discount your products temporarily"
          action={{
            content: "Select products",
            onAction: () => setResourcePicker,
          }}
        ></EmptyState>
      </Layout>
    </Page>
  );
}

const handleSelection = (resources) => {
  console.log(resources);
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Can someone help set me in the right direction here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this line:

```
onAction: () => setResourcePicker,
```

The function is not being called and you need to pass a value in. In order to match the functionality of the class version, it should be:

```
onAction: () => setResourcePicker({ open: true }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overly complexifying things. You don't need to put objects inside `useState` unless required. `useCallback` is beneficial if your function changes too much and performs expensive computations, in your case, it's not required.

```
const [resourcePicker, setResourcePicker] = useState({ open: false });
  const handleToggleResourcePicker = useCallback(
    () => setResourcePicker((active) => !active),
    []
  );
```

can be changed into

```
const [resourcePicker, setResourcePicker] = useState(false);
const handleToggleResourcePicker = () => {
  setResourcePicker(active => !active)
}
```

Rest I would suggest you to read [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)